# mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server

Tags: domain-name-system, nfs

I have a problem with nfs client not being able to resolve a resolvable DNS name.

```
[root@testserver-2 ~]# host nfs-server-host-name
nfs-server-host-name has address 10.37.4.131

[root@testserver-2 ~]# nslookup nfs-server-host-name
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Name:   nfs-server-host-name
Address: 10.37.4.126

[root@testserver-2 ~]# showmount -e nfs-server-host-name
clnt_create: RPC: Unknown host

[root@testserver-2 ~]# ss -lnp |grep rpc
LISTEN     0      128                       *:111                      *:*      users:(("rpcbind",7627,8)

[root@testserver-2 ~]# mount -t nfs -o defaults,auto,proto=tcp nfs-server-host-name:/ifs/exports/EXPORT /mnt/export
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server nfs-server-host-name: Name or service not known
```

Local resolving is set up via dnsmasq:

```
[root@testserver-2 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
options rotate timeout:2 attempts:4
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 10.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8

[root@testserver-2 ~]# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf 
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf
server=/nfs-server-host-name/10.37.4.1 #IP address of Isilon smart connect resolver
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

nsswitch configuration (default Centos 6):

```
[root@testserver-2 ~]# grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files dns
```

Please note that `nfs-server-host-name` resolving is handled by an Isilon smart connect resolver, which is configured as a resolver for `nfs-server-host-name` locally via dnsmasq and works (as seen in the above example). Replacing `nfs-server-host-name` with an IP address is not an option as there are multiple NFS nodes which are balanced by the resolver therefore the IP is variable and cannot be hardcoded. It is therefore OK that the two results above from hosts and nslookup are different. *This is intended and expected behaviour.*

Please also note that `nfs-server-host-name` is a very precise example of what the hostname looks like. The actual hostname looks almost identically, it's not a FQDN. In fact there are no dots in the hostname at all. This is a feature I'm not in control of.

When mounted manually with one valid node IP address the export mounts fine. When one node's address is put to `/etc/hosts`, it mounts. When resolved via DNS means, it does not work for the nfs client but works for other net tools such as hosts, dig or ping.

This seems to be not-so-uncommon problem but all tips I found so far say "replace hostname with IP" which is something I cannot do.

What I missed?

Comment: What does `nslookup` return?

Comment: nslookup behaves as expected, responds with IP address of the host and 127.0.0.1 as the dns server queried (which is ok, it's the local dnsmasq). I'll add the output to the question, thanks

Comment: What does the `hosts` entry in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` say? If it has only `files`, or something like `files [NOTFOUND=return] dns`, the libc resolver will never even try to use DNS.

Comment: `hosts:      files dns`, that's it. Will add to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have yet to figure out what the **real** problem is but the solution is to remove `rotate` option from `/etc/resolv.conf` **and** put a dot after `nfs-server-host-name` in `/etc/fstab` to prevent domain search (which occurred even when there was no `search` option in `/etc/resolv.conf`), i.e.:

```
nfs-server-host-name.:/nfs/export/...
                    ^
                    ^---up here
```

It may have something to do with kernel build option CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS, which is set to *yes* on my kernel.

The behaviour of nfs-client (and nfs-client only) was that it only queried the **second** nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` no matter how many there were as long as the `rotate` option was present. It did, however, work when there was no second nameserver at all. Beats me...

Comment: I wonder if this also happens on more recent LTS kernels...

Answer (score 2):

The `showmount` command has an RPC call which uses `gethostbyname_r` to attempt to get information for a hostname. It does not do much to interpret errors returned by it. Could you run a test to see what the error actually is? This code is modified from the actual glibc `clnt_gen.c` code seen [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/a2f34833b1042d5d8eeb263b4cf4caaea138c4ad/sunrpc/clnt_gen.c)

Example C source:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hostent hostbuf, *h;
    size_t hstbuflen;
    char *hsttmpbuf;
    char *hostname;
    int herr;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
      exit(-1);
    }
    hostname = argv[1];

    hstbuflen = 1024;
    hsttmpbuf = alloca(hstbuflen);
    while (gethostbyname_r (hostname, &hostbuf, hsttmpbuf, hstbuflen, &h, &herr) != 0 || h == NULL)
    {
        if (herr != NETDB_INTERNAL || errno != ERANGE)
        {
            printf("gethostbyname_r error: %s\n", hstrerror(herr));
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            hstbuflen *= 2;
            hsttmpbuf = alloca (hstbuflen);
        }
    }
}
```

Save this as `ghbntest.c` and compile with the command `gcc -o ghbntest ghbntest.c`. Run using `./ghbntest nfs-server-host-name`. Output example:

```
$ ./ghbntest 12345.example.com
gethostbyname_r error: Unknown host
```

Comment: thanks, it says `gethostbyname_r error: Unknown host` when there is no entry in `/etc/hosts` and nothing when the entry is there.

One thing I may have been more clear about is that the example name `nfs-server-host-name` is actually a more precise example than one would think - there are actually no dots in the host name (and no `search` option in `/etc/resolv.conf`)

Comment: I had a hunch that it would have been related to the hostname you're providing not being a FQDN. I'll bet if you provide the hostname with a trailing period to the test program, you won't get an error. It seems in your other reply that that worked out to be the solution for your original NFS problem.

Comment: The non-fqdn name was just a part of the problem, the other one being nfs client using incorrect nameserver to resolve the the name in the first place, as described in my answer. Both the problems however point to messed up dns resolving implemented in nfs client as it did ask the wrong server **and** filled in a search domain even though it was not supposed to. I have yet to figure out where did nfs client got the fqdn part - the only configuration where the entry was present was the host's hostname. Network is configured statically.

Comment: returncode 16, but no output, is what I'm getting.